# am I overloading my actionListener? JFileChooser

Tags: java, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I am attempting to load a saved file from JFileChooser using an actionListener. Here is a snippet of code.

```
class chooserListener implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {   
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JFileChooser){
                    JFileChooser openFile = (JFileChooser)e.getSource();
                    String command = e.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)){
                        File selectedFile = openFile.getSelectedFile();

                        loadSavedGame(selectedFile);
                        System.out.print("clicked open file");
                        tp.setSelectedIndex(0);
                    }
                    else if (command.equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                          System.out.print("tester");
                          tp.setSelectedIndex(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
chooser.addActionListener(new chooserListener());

public void loadSavedGame(File loadfile) {

        int allCells = countCells(loadfile);
        setMineGame(allCells);

        try {
            Scanner loadFile = new Scanner(loadfile);
            while (loadFile.hasNextInt()){
                for (int i = 0; i < allCells; i++){
                    mineGame.setCell(i, loadFile.nextInt());
                    //System.out.print("loading saved game");  
                }
                loadFile.close();
                mineGame.repaint();
                tp.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private int countCells(File countCell) {

    int cellCount = 0;

    try {
        Scanner getCells = new Scanner(countCell);
        while (getCells.hasNextInt()){
            cellCount++;

        }
        getCells.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print(cellCount);
    return cellCount;
}

public void setMineGame(int cells) {
    game.removeAll();
    mineGame.setDifficulty(cells);
    mineGame = new Board(statusbar, difficulty);
    game.add(mineGame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    game.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();

}   
public void setDifficulty(int cells){

        if(cells == 256){
            difficulty = 0;
        }
        if (cells == 676){
            difficulty = 1;
        }
        else difficulty = 2;
    }
```

I feel like I have too many methods for the action listener to do. It is hanging when I click 'open', and the test print line 'System.out.print("clicked open file");' does not print.  the rest of my code is really large and I'm not sure how to to an SSCE(?). I'm wondering if anyone can see why my actionListener is hanging? thanks IA

Comment: There's no way the code you've posted will run at all. Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: In the `loadSavedGame` method, `loadFile.close()` needs to be outside the `while` loop, and `mineGame.repaint()` probably should be as well.

Comment: thank you @VGR, I tried this but the actionListener still hangs :-(. I'm not even sure where to start to break it down to make an SSCCE work, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `loadSavedGame(File file)` takes a lot of time to execute. As this method is running in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) you feel like your program is hanging and never reaches `System.out.print("clicked open file");` line. I'd start testing the time of response for this method in a separate test case

Anyway I'd suggest you a few tips:

1) Note there's no need to implement an `ActionListener` to do your code. You can simple make this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    //make stuff if approved
} else if(returnValue == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
    //make stuff if canceled
}
```

I think it makes people life easier.

2) On the other hand note you have two I/O operations: getting the cells count through `countCells(File countCell)` method and getting the cells themselves inside `loadSavedGame(File loadfile)` method. You can do it better reading the file just once:

```
public List<Integer> getCells(File file){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {    
        Scanner getCells = new Scanner(file);
        while (getCells.hasNextInt()){
            list.add(Integer.valueOf(getCells.nextInt()));

        }
        getCells.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
          return list;
    }
}
```

And make this change in `loadSavedGame` method:

```
public void loadSavedGame(File loadfile) {

    List<Integer> allCells = getCells(loadfile);
    setMineGame(allCells.size());
    int index = 0;

    for(Integer value : allCells){
        mineGame.setCell(index, value);
        index++;
    }

    mineGame.repaint();
    tp.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this code, I am still learning about collections and array lists so wasn't sure how to implement this at all. But I copied your code and it's working perfectly! The only thing is the chooser is supposed to be inside a tab, it isn't showing in the tab now tho. I think its got something to do with the 'chooser.showOpenDialog(null). I have added the chooser to the tab (at index[1]). can you give me any further guidance to get the chooser back into the tab, or should I ask a new question? Thank you so much again :-)

Comment: You're most welcome! And I'm very happy it worked for you :-) Sorry but I didn't use `JFileChooser` inside a `JPanel` before. Note this component is commonly intended to show a separate modal dialog to force user make a selection before continue. I think you can add a `JMenu` instead with a `JMenuItem` called *Load saved game...* and show the `JFileChooser` when user clicks this option. It's a pretty common design in games.